# Recursive C++ Function To Move Specific Characters To End Of String

Tags: c++, string, recursion

I am attempting to write a recursive function that, given a string, recursively computes a new string where all the lowercase 'x' chars have been moved to the end of the string.

For example, 
   moveXs("xxre") --> "rexx"
   moveXs("xxhixx") --> "hixxxx"
   moveXs("xhixhix") --> "hihixxx"

I am relatively new to C++ and especially to recursion (unfortunately the function must employ this method to solve the problem), so I am having trouble with this problem. Below is the code I have written thus far, but it seems to be returning only empty strings and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

```
string moveXs(const string& str)
{
    string strCopy = str;
    if (strCopy.length() <= 1)
    {
        return str;
    }
    else if (strCopy[0] == 'x')
    {
        strCopy = strCopy.substr(1, strCopy.length() - 1) + str[0];
        return moveXs(strCopy.substr(0, (strCopy.length() - 2)));
    }
    else
    {
        return strCopy.substr(0, 1) + moveXs(strCopy.substr(1, strCopy.length() - 1));
    }
}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just had some indexing issues. I modified your code here, and note the new returns. Also I got rid of the extraneous second string.

```
string moveXs(const string& str)
{
    if (str.length() <= 1)
    {
        return str;
    }
    else if (str[0] == 'x')
    {
        return moveXs(str.substr(1, (str.length() - 1))) + str[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return str[0] + moveXs(str.substr(1, str.length()));
    }
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://ideone.com/aT75l5

Comment: Comparing your edit to mine, I was able to see exactly where I went wrong with the indexing. Removing the strCopy string also made the coder a lot cleaner. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach could be just traverse the string from beginning to end counting and removing 'x'. Then append 'x' count number of times in previous string.

Comment: You should be able to make that tail-recursive too, so it could be optimised out.

Answer (score -1):

```
string MoveX(string str,int n){
  if(n==0 || n==1){
    return str;
  }
  if(str[n-1]=='x'){
    str[n-1]=str[n-1]-'x';
    str=str+"x";
  }
    string atr=MoveX(str,n-1);
    return atr;

}
```