# How to put the char with the smallest ASCII value at the end of the String recursively?

Tags: java, string, recursion

Given the method:

```
public String moveSmallest(String s) {}
```

how to find the char with the smallest ASCII value, place it at the end of the String, and return that String, **recursively**?

Reading [Find a char..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597546/find-a-character-recursively-in-a-string), [Move the char..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416879/recursive-c-function-to-move-specific-characters-to-end-of-string), [Move to end..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536852/recursion-moving-char-to-the-end-of-the-string/50537157) didn't really answer: what is the algorithm I need, and how do I implement it.

No global vars, accumulators, helper methods, or any additional structures can be used.

This question is closely connected (in nature) to [How to pass a partial solution to the next recursive call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583756/how-to-work-on-the-same-array-across-the-recursion-stack-or-how-to-pass-a-part).

Attempt to find the min char:

```
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        return s;
    } else if (s.length() > 1) {
        char c = s.charAt(0) > moveSmallest(s.substring(1)).charAt(s.length()-1) ? s.charAt(0) : moveSmallest(s.substring(1)).charAt(s.length()-1);    
    }
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you really want to use recursion, here it is.

**Move smallest letter to the end:**

```
public static String moveSmallestToTheEnd(String s) {
    if (s.length() <= 1)
        return s;
    if (s.length() == 2)
        return s.charAt(0) < s.charAt(1) ? String.valueOf(s.charAt(1)) + s.charAt(0) : s;

    String suffix = s.substring(1);
    String res = moveSmallestToTheEnd(suffix);
    return s.charAt(0) < res.charAt(res.length() - 1) ? suffix + s.charAt(0) : s.charAt(0) + res;
}
```

*Output:*

```
a -> a
ab -> ba
ba -> ba
abc -> bca
bac -> bca
bca -> bca
bcdae -> bcdea
bcae -> bcea
```

**Move higest letter to the beginning:**

```
public static String moveHighestToTheBeginning(String s) {
    if (s.length() <= 1)
        return s;
    if (s.length() == 2)
        return s.charAt(0) < s.charAt(1) ? String.valueOf(s.charAt(1)) + s.charAt(0) : s;

    String prefix = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
    String res = moveHighestToTheBeginning(prefix);
    return s.charAt(s.length() - 1) > res.charAt(0) ? s.charAt(s.length() - 1) + prefix : res + s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
}
```

*Output:*

```
a -> a
ab -> ba
ba -> ba
abc -> cab
bac -> cba
bca -> cba
bcdae -> ebcda
bcae -> ebca
```

Comment: @Dallmayer Das is sehr einfach!